# PIP Mode for WebRTC video calls in iOS

Tags: webrtc, picture-in-picture, webrtc-ios, ant-media-server-sdk

I have started working on the PIP functionality for IOS. I finished my rendering with RTCMTLVideoView. Then I realised what I'd done wrong: MTKView/GLKView aren't supported in pip mode. Now I intend to Create frame render to display user's video instead of RTCMTLVideoView/RTCEAGLVideoView . But I can't proceed since I can't convert RTCVideoTrack to RTCVideoFrame. Any code fragments or branches where we can discover the idea/solution would be really appreciated.

/*

1. get videoTrackObject
2. convert RTCVideoTrack to RTCVideoFrame
3. create pixelBuffer using RTCVideoFrame
4. create CMSampleBuffer using CVPixelBuffer
5. update in the localView/remoteview UI using cmSampleBuffer
6. implement PIP related methods.
   */

I referred following links to achieve the pip for video calls:
pip for webrtc video calls in ios
adopting_picture_in_picture_for_video_calls
accessing_the_camera_while_multitasking_on_ipad

Comment: No.. I didn't get any solution.